# form using ajax,php and jquery - to action or not to action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

a basic question from a total jquery/ajax newbie.

I have a simple form with two input fields for which I want the data passed via jquery and ajax to a php file on my server side. After processing, it should send me a nice reply back like "request was processed" or some other text.

I have searched the web and this forum and I found that not all posts/webpages/tutorials describe this in the same way. So now, I am a bit lost in the abundance of information.

First question: in all tutorials, the form is inside an .html file (like index.html). In my case, the form is in a .php file. Does this have any influence in how the form is treated. The form is written in html syntax so it should not matter if it is an .html or in a .php file, correct?

Second question:

In some tutorials, the form action will link to the php file where the data is sent. Method is usually "POST". 
Then, in the jquery file, the $.ajax url also points to that same php file.

Is this the correct way to do it?

If I set it up like that, upon clicking the submit button, the browser is always directed to the php file in the form-action and the jquery file I wrote is not executed. 
And I have no clue why this happens.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have:

```
<?php
<form action="distant.php" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="form-element" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit form" />
</form>
<div id="message"></div>
?>
```

You can do this in jQuery:

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // do not try to access distant.php by reloading the page
    $.ajax({
        type     : "POST",
        url      : $(this).attr('action'), // access distant.php by ajax
        data     : $(this).serialize(), // get values from the form. In this case, only one element (with name="form-element")
        success  : function(data) {
            // response from distant.php - could be "request was processed" if you want
            $("#message").html(data); // display the response in the html
        }
    });
});
```

But, I don't see the point by mixing html and php.

Comment: Like I said before, due to the abundance of information, I was mixing up everything.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer what I know so far,

> 1. for the file extension it should works for .php, .html or .json. The ajax just will get the return as dataType has you declared (html
>      or json).
>
>    2. For the type you can use POST or GET, it depend on what the need. But for your problem (the ajax can not executed), you have to always
>         check the sending data of ajax by opening inspect element (by right
>         clicking on browser, chrome is recommended). Then you click the
>         'network' tab. you can see there if there is an error. (always
>         debuging code of your data code by die($query) for example). 
>         Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether the file type is php, html, aspx etc.  The output that is sent to the browser will all be treated the same by the client.

Your question references two different ways of POSTing data to the backend and you're sort of mixing and matching the two.

a simple:

```
<form action="/somepage.php" method="post"></form>
```

is the most standard way to post data from a client to a server.  It's probably a good starting point for you to learn with.  AJAX does the same thing but it does it w/o changing the URL of the loaded page thereby keeping the current page loaded and asynchronously sending the data to the server.  Usually in the latter scenario, you'll still want to manipulate the DOM or show some feedback to the user to indicate that their data has been submitted.

As I said before, I think you should start with a standard form post to your back end and on the action page, show the "results".  This is a much better jumping off point to learn the interactions between client and server side.

Comment: Hi Blair, I know how to pass data with a 'post' method. But I wanted to do this without refreshing URL. However, what is happening and which I do not understand is the following: when I define a form action like in your example, this is always executed, no matter if I have defined a Jquery script. The moment I press the "submit" button, the browser is redirected to the /somepage.php without executing the jquery first.

Comment: that is normal behavior.  a "submit" button will always SUBMIT the form unless that event is captured and prevented.  Look at using a regular button instead `<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="SomeButtonId" />`